# Outlook 2016 password prompt

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

We have exchange 2010 and Exchange 2016, All the user mailboxes were moved to Exchange 2016. Now all the connections are redirected to Exchange 2016, Exchange 2010 will be decommissioned soon

After the mailbox is moved to exchange server 2016, We have noticed that any user has changed the password and logged in to domain joined computer and if they open the outlook, the new password used for windows login is not automatically taken for outlook, Instead outlook is asking for user to provide the password, after the new password is provided, the outlook profile is connected. Outlook version is 2016.

I have suspected this could be due to Negotiate authentication when using MAPI over HTTP protocol, So i removed the Negotiate authentication from Autodiscover, MAPI and EWS front end virtual directories in exchange server 2016, After this the authentication method used is NTLM, but the behavior is same when the user change the password and login to windows and open the outlook.

Please share your experience and thoughts on this.

How make the outlook client to get connect the mailbox automatically once the user has logged in to windows using the new password ?

Comment: Closing - Answered off-site as link-only; Default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that you may have posted the same question in both communities, I saw someone already answered it for you in Microsoft Q&A, he mentioned that this might be expected behavior, you can refer to your post in Microsoft Q&A.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1337914/outlook-2016-password-prompt?orderby=helpful#answers

Comment: Its good of you to spot it, but this is not an answer. You can improve it by copying the salient points over and leave the link as a credit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi All, This has been confirmed as the default behavior, Thank you all for the support.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, if this reply is helpful to you, you can consider marking it as an answer.